# Could a photon interact with itself disrupting its path?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, photons, double-slit-experiment

I don't have a physics background, just a hobbyist. I just started taking differential geometry to try and understand the math behind relativity, and have limited knowledge of Quantum mechanics.

I recently watched a video explaining the interference pattern in the double slit experiment using oil droplets. In the video, they said that it doesn't accurately capture real quantum mechanics because the photon passes through both slits but it got me thinking why couldn't that be the case?

My understanding is that photons disrupt space-time, but not enough to make a noticeable difference for most things. But would it be enough to disrupt itself from the slit that the photon doesn't pass through? If this were the case, then we could treat a photon as a particle but the path it travels would be disrupted by its own gravity.

Could someone explain why this wouldn't work?

Comment: "My understanding is that photons disrupt space-time" that is new to me

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Maybe the OP means only "affect" instead of "disrupt", in the context of GR.

Comment: Since we know spin-2 theories are not renormalizable, talking about self interaction is not going to...converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photons have no identity. They are called identical or [indistinguishable particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical_particles). So the phrase "disrupt itself" does not really have that much meaning. When determining photon properties, we have to evaluate their statistical behaviour in ensembles of many of them. This is described in the [statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_statistics) that describe photons.

> because the photon passes through both slits but it got me thinking why couldn't that be the case?

When an attempt is made to detect from which of the two slits the photon emerges, we find it at this one slit. The photons either go through one slit or the other and do not "split into two then interfere". This is a common misconception. However if it is not detected, we find that the interference pattern that forms seems to suggest that it passed through both at the same time. But you need to think of the photon as being in a [superposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_superposition). It has a *probability* of passing through either slit.

> My understanding is that photons disrupt space-time

Photons have energy and momentum, and would have non-zero components in the Einstein stress-energy-momentum tensor. Therefore they can cause space-time to curve.

> But would it be enough to disrupt itself from the slit that the photon doesn't pass through?

So if this question is asking if the photon splits and each part goes through each slit, then can they influence each other gravitationally? Please read above points. They are not splitting.

> If this were the case, then we could treat a photon as a particle but the path it travels would be disrupted by its own gravity.
>
> Could someone explain why this wouldn't work?

Particles have both wave and particle characteristics simultaneously. I'm going to say that there is no photon that has so much energy that the space-time surrounding it would be so warped that its own path would be distorted, so much so, that we could measure it. This affect and the [double slit interference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment) are two completely different things though.